# Kubeflow Pipelines - Passing String to Output

Tags: kubeflow

What is the simplest way to send along a string through the outputs in a Kubeflow Pipeline? I would like to have a timestamp created in my first component and then send that timestamp to each successive step in the pipeline.

The only way I have seen to send outputs is by file path in the docs. Here is a portion of my component.yaml file that shows what I mean:

```
name: CSV Filter
description: Connects to GCSPath and filters columns using specific column name
inputs:
- {name: Training Set URI, type: GCSPath, description: 'GCS path to training set CSV'}
- {name: Filter Column, type: String, default: 'model_type', description: 'Filter Column Name'}
- {name: Filter Value, type: String, description: 'The value you are filtering for.'}
- {name: Output 1 URI template, type: GCSPath, description: 'GCS path template for filtered training set CSV'}
outputs:
- {name: Output 1 URI, type: GCSPath, description: 'GCS path for filtered training set CSV'}
- {name: Timetag File, type: GCSPath, description: 'Timetag based on time since last UNIX Epoch. Used for version control.'}
```

The area of interest is the "Timetag File" in outputs. Instead of creating a file, I just want to send over a string. Is it sufficient to just change "type: GCSPath" to "type: String", so that in my pipeline step, I will be able to access that string?

In other words, Should I just save the string to a file path in my python code within the component or is there a better way?

Comment: try to check this https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/sdk/static-type-checking/

Comment: I am wondering about this too.